# chrome extension to click a tag link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build an extension that will retrieve the  tag link and if it matches a certain word the link would be clicked.  The only problem is I can't use the click() method because the a tag does not contain an id or class name.  How would I go about clicking the link or just to redirect chrome to go to the link?

Comment: so you want when page is loaded, to check all links for certain word, and if there is a match, automatically redirect to it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  redirect or click on the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this in your content script

```
   var links = document.getElementsByTagName('A');

   for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].href.indexOf('certain_word') > -1) links[i].click();  
        break;  
    }
```

Comment: thanks this worked. I thought I couldn't use the click() method.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

window.location works fine. Just pass the href value when you find the matched content